# Group according to regular expression in dplyr

Tags: r

I have some data as follows

```
                          X2   Prop
 eosinophilicoesophagitisscop  0.7
                       furrow  7
                       oedema 16
                      oedemat  1
        oesophagealtrachealis  0
                   oesophagit 25
           oesophagitisbiopsi  0.2
       oesophagitisendoscopic  0
             oesophagitiseros  0
            oesophagitisgastr  0
                        plaqu 16
```

I would like to group words that match the following:

```
 myNotableWords<-c("oesophagit","oedema","furrow","plaq")
```

so that I end up with:

```
oesophagit  25.9
furrow      7
oedema      17
plaq        16
```

I tried the following

```
library(dplyr)
mywords<-foo %>%
    group_by(foo[grepl(paste(myNotableWords, collapse='|'), X2,perl=TRUE),])
    summarise(n=n())
```

but I get the error:

```
 Error: wrong result size (3), expected 11 or 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the notable words, `grep` it and then get the `sum` of the 'Prop' column

```
v1 <- sapply(myNotableWords, function(x) sum(df1$Prop[grep(x, df1$X2)]))
data.frame(words = names(v1), val = as.vector(v1))
#      words  val
#1 oesophagit 25.9
#2     oedema 17.0
#3     furrow  7.0
#4       plaq 16.0
```

---

This can be also done with `dplyr` after extracting the relevant words with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp = str_extract(X2, paste(myNotableWords, collapse="|"))) %>% 
   summarise(Prop = sum(Prop)) %>%
   na.omit()
# A tibble: 4 × 2
#        grp  Prop
#       <chr> <dbl>
#1     furrow   7.0
#2     oedema  17.0
#3 oesophagit  25.9
#4       plaq  16.0
```

---

Or a similar option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df1)[, .(Prop = sum(Prop)), 
        .(grp = str_extract(X2, paste(myNotableWords, collapse="|")))])
```

Comment: `df[ , sapply(myNotableWords, function(x) sum(Prop[grepl(x, X2)]))]` for `data.table` too. Just to make it complete :)

Comment: @joel.wilson  I would use `lapply` with `unlist` ie. `df1[ , .(grp = myNotableWords, val = unlist(lapply(myNotableWords, function(x) sum(Prop[grepl(x, X2)]))))]`

Answer (score 2):

A `purrr` solution, with the notable words as the starting data, and using nested data frames. No grouping required.

```
data_frame(word = myNotableWords) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(word, ~foo[grepl(., foo$X2), ]),
         sum = map_dbl(data, ~sum(.x$Prop)))
```